# Automating internet option in IE 9 to open pop ups in new window through code asp or Jscript in asp coded page

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, internet-explorer-9

Please let me know if i can open a pop up window in a new browser instead of a new tab if the ie9 setting is default. My code is in ASP.

this is already present in the code but its not working.

Please help

Comment: That's beyond your control. When you specify `target='_blank'`, it's up to the browser to decide what that means

Comment: Hi Matt, my issue is i want to forcefully open the new link in a new browser, could you please suggest if it's at all possible ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code which might help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open('YourPageName.asp','','menubar=1, toolbar=0, scrollbars=1, status=1,resizable=1,width=650, height=500, top=10,left=100');
</script>
```

copy and paste this code where you want to open the popup window. Replace 'YourPageName' parameter with the name of the page you want to open in popup